# Jquery get raw source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the raw html code(what I see in chrome source code window) in JQuery. I have tried html(), but it is converting all of quotes to &quot. I have tried text(), but it is the opposite, converting html symbols to text. I have the following source code in my browser, I want to remove the & #034; text, but I could not get it with above mentioned methods. How can I get it?

```
    {
        "description": "RUS/SANKT-PETERBU/Hotel &#034;ANNUSHKA&#034;"
    },
```

text method is showing the following:

```
    {
            "description": "RUS/SANKT-PETERBU/Hotel "ANNUSHKA""
    },
```

html method is showing the following:

```
    {           
        &quot;description&quot;: &quot;RUS/SANKT-PETERBU/Hotel &quot;ANNUSHKA&quot;&quot;
    },
```

Comment: No, It is not what I want.

Comment: I think, you use jQuery/JavaScript in wrong way. Can you explain your task?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var obj = { "description": "RUS/SANKT-PETERBU/Hotel &#034;ANNUSHKA&#034;" }
obj.description.replace(/&#034;/g, '')
```

I'm not sure that I understand your question.